# git pull doesn't recognize the files it "pulls"

Tags: git

In previous projects I used to use a cron job that would run "svn up" to keep a test site up to date.

I'm trying to reproduce the same in a new project that uses git.

```
*/5 * * * * cd /path/to/project; git checkout .;  sudo -u nonrootuser git pull >/dev/null 2>> /path/to/project/cron.log; chgrp web . -R;
```

I added the initial git checkout . to see if I could solve the issue, but it persists. The issue is as follows, about once a week, I get this message:

```
error: Your local changes to 'path/to/aFileThatDidntExistLocally.xxx' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting. Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

But that file really didn't exist before the pull command. Its almost as if the git pull command is fetching the files, staging them, then as if struck with Alzheimer, failing to recognize having created the file, and thus aborting because the file is already there.

Even if I delete the file, it happens again. It will also happen if I run a simple "git pull" with my root user. Also it seems to be kind of random, its happened to me about three times in the past three weeks. All the rest of the time the cron job works as expected, every 5 minutes.

The only way I've found to get it to pull correctly again is to run "git clean -f", but its not something I want to place in my cron job because it removes all of my untracked files.

I suspect the commits/pushes, but I don't see anything out of the ordinary. What is going on, and how can I consistently update my test site without having to remove all untracked files each time?

(edit)
Here are a copy of my .gitignore and .git/config files: http://pastebin.com/SxXbshuN

Comment: Does your git repository's .git/config file look healthy? (especially if there is a work tree path entry)

Comment: Your question is a bit of a he-said she-said. You say the file didn't exist there, git says it does. Most courts would side with git in this matter, but why don't you begin with providing some more details regarding what kind of file it actually is causing the trouble, it's name and so on, as well as what kind of software it is you're git pulling?

Comment: Don't see the point, if you work on the project a git pull in background will always produce such errors if you made some conflicting changes locally. If it's just for backup reasons you pull the repo then go with `git clean` or even better use a bare repo.
Perhaps a `git pull --rebase` might be what you could try if it's really what you want.

Comment: @JosefAssad you are saying that you don't believe me when I tell you I rm the file -f, run git status and its not there, then pull and git says its already there?

Comment: @buergi no, no one touches the test site. Its there so all team members can view everyone's latest pushed changes. The only local changes are images and cache files that get written to ignored folders.

Comment: @JosefAssad As to what kind of file, the last issue was caused by new php template files being added by one of the developers.

Comment: It's hard to post a solution without knowing what's going on, did you tried a `git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master`? It sounds really weird, perhaps posting a sample command line session of yours helps.

Comment: @buergi no I didn't try that combination this time around. Remember the issue occurs while updating via cron. This time all I did when I noticed the issue was delete the "offending", files, run git pull again, and since the issue persisted, I ran git clean -f -d; I will add rebase to the cron job to see if that helps..

Comment: No Tom I'm not saying I don't believe you. :)  don't think git is magicking files out of thin air though. There's no answers here yet, and when that is the case it's usually because people don't have enough specific details to work with. Posting the precise filenames, your git config, more specific descriptions of the files involved, and so on will help.

Comment: @JosefAssad Thanks. As per the description, git isn't "inventing" the files; git was supposed to add the new files in that pull. It adds the first file, then fails complaining that it already exists. Here are my .gitignore and .git/config: http://pastebin.com/SxXbshuN